# Kali Linux does not load after installation

Tags: linux, windows-8, multi-boot, grub, uefi

I wanted to dual boot 8.1 pro and Kali Linux, so did the basic steps

1. Created around 100 GB of free space (I know its too much).
2. Then tried USB installation, USB worked fine (created it using USBwriter).
3. Then went for disk manual and chose 4 GB for swap area and rest as ext4 for installation.
4. When it shows "A network mirror can be used to supplement the software that is included on the CD-ROM. This may also make newer versions of software available" I chose NO.
5. Install the GRUB boot loader to the master boot record?
   again selected NO. After this it should show a new selecting between

   1. Enter device manually
   2. `/dev/sda`

It did not show anything but I continued to install. When it was complete and after the restart it took me directly to Windows (ps as instructed I removed the USB so it does not take me again to boot menu).

Someone  tell me what went wrong and if anyone better way of dual booting
(Everything was instructed from a tutorial and GRUB was installed during installation and I was connected to Wi-Fi during installation, live run is fine)

Comment: Why would you choose no when prompted to install grub?  Grub is the thing that allows you to select operating systems at boot.  Without it, Windows cannot even see the Kali install because it's on a type of file system that it cannot read (natively at least).

Comment: Grub was installed, but not configured to be the default bootloader.  You need to choose yes at that part of the install.

Comment: I created a system rescue disk and after not installing grub,I was trying to boot from rescue disk and make adjustment from there. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's easy to run maximum Linux distro (specifically Kali Linux) in Legacy mode from a live USB run, but problems will arise when you will shift from LEGACY to UEFI manually from BIOS menu.

Like the distro which were running fine in LEGACY may not work now, to fix this you will have to write your USB in UEFI mode. There are many USB writer out there to use, you can use any from your choice.

But specifically for Kali Linux I will suggest using Win32DiskImager because it's ISO is not EFI bootable. If you want to try use Rufus for it, Rufus will show you the error and will not write on USB but many other software will simply write on USB using MBR. So be careful about it.

Also if you want, you can create USB in MBR and edit it manually for EFI booting. (Google it for more info or comment below if you don't find anything)